# PHP posting array values generated in JS for loop

Tags: javascript, php

I am using this script to generate a code which will later appear in a form.
I have this code working on 2 pages, but I have no idea why it is not able to post to te next page.

Below is my code:

```
   function add(){



var coun    = document.getElementById('count').value; 

if(coun==""){var count = 1;}
else{var count = (coun*1)+1;}


if(count>=1){
show('cont_del');   
}

var field       = "";
var table       = "";
var desc_arr    = "";
var itn_arr     = "";
var qty_arr     = "";
var cls_arr     = "";
var unp_arr     = "";
var tot_arr     = "";




for(var f=1;f<count;f++){

    desc_arr    = document.getElementById('desc'+f).value;
    itn_arr     = document.getElementById('itn'+f).value;
    qty_arr     = document.getElementById('qty'+f).value;
    <? if($_POST['type']=="o"){ ?>
    cls_arr     = document.getElementById('cls'+f).value;
    <? } ?>
    unp_arr     = document.getElementById('unp'+f).value;
    tot_arr     = document.getElementById('tot'+f).value;


    field = field+"<table class='style5'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";
    field = field+"<td width='70'><b>"+f+"</b></td>\n";
<? if($_POST['type']!="s"){ ?>  
    field = field+"<td width='130'>";
    field = field+"<input name='itn[]' id='itn"+f+"' type='text' class='input' size='5' maxlength='11' value='"+itn_arr+"'>";
    field = field+"</td>\n";
<? } ?> 
    field = field+"<td width='200'>";
    field = field+"<input name='desc[]' id='desc"+f+"' type='text'
  class='input' size='30' value='"+desc_arr+"'>";
    field = field+"</td>\n";                            
    field = field+"<td width='70'>";
    field = field+"<input name='qty[]' id='qty"+f+"'
 onchange='totcalc("+f+");' type='text' class='input' size='3' 
value='"+qty_arr+"'>";
    field = field+"</td>\n";
<? if($_POST['type']=="o"){ ?>          
    field = field+"<td width='70'>";
    field = field+"<input name='cls[]' id='cls"+f+"' type='text'
 class='input' size='3' value='"+cls_arr+"'>";
    field = field+"</td>\n";
<? } ?>         
    field = field+"<td width='150'>";
    field = field+"<input name='unp[]' id='unp"+f+"' 
    onchange='totcalc("+f+");digit("+f+")' type='text' class='input' 
    size='10' value='"+unp_arr+"'>";
    field = field+"</td>\n";
    field = field+"<td width='150'>";
    field = field+"<input name='tot[]' id='tot"+f+"' type='text' 
    class='input' size='10' value='"+tot_arr+"'>";
    field = field+"</td>\n";
    field = field+"</tr></table>\n\n";

}


var table = "<table class='style5'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";
    table = table+"<td width='70'><b>"+count+"</b></td>\n";
<? if($_POST['type']!="s"){ ?>      
    table = table+"<td width='130'>";
    table = table+"<input name='itn[]' id='itn"+count+"' type='text'
 class='input' size='5' maxlength='11'>";
    table = table+"</td>\n";
<? } ?>     
    table = table+"<td width='200'>";
    table = table+"<input name='desc[]' id='desc"+count+"' type='text'
 class='input' size='30'>";
    table = table+"</td>\n";
    table = table+"<td width='70'>";
    table = table+"<input name='qty[]' id='qty"+count+"' 
onchange='totcalc("+count+");' type='text' class='input' size='3'   
value='0'>";
    table = table+"</td>\n";
<? if($_POST['type']=="o"){ ?>  
    table = table+"<td width='70'>";
    table = table+"<input name='cls[]' id='cls"+count+"' type='text'     
class='input' size='3'";
    table = table+"</td>\n";
<? } ?>         
    table = table+"<td width='150'>";
    table = table+"<input name='unp[]' id='unp"+count+"' 
onchange='totcalc("+count+"); digit("+count+")' type='text' 
class='input' size='10' value='0.00'>";
    table = table+"</td>\n";
    table = table+"<td width='150'>";
    table = table+"<input name='tot[]' id='tot"+count+"'  
    type='text' class='input' size='10' value='0.00'>";
    table = table+"</td>\n";
    table = table+"</tr></table>\n\n";



    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = field + table;

    document.getElementById("count").value = (count*1);
}
```

Later everything will be posted to the a div id='add' container in a nested table.

When I post the form there are no variables posted.

Comment: where is your form html?

Comment: Dunno if I didnt get you wrong, but is this file.js or file.php with <script type="javascript>? You cannot use PHP in a .js file, so obv. it wont work.

Comment: HTML is on top. I just copied and pasted my JS here.
It's a .php file.

Comment: Hard for anyone to assess a form problem when no form code is shown and no ajax ( if that is being used). Suggest you create a smaller test version for yourself

Comment: I'm just posting from a form. It's really a lot of code.

<form action="orderseditact.php" method="post" >
    <tr>
     <td colspan='2'>Customer: </td>
    </tr>...

<div id='add'></div>

...    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td>
      <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?=$id;?>'>
     

      <input type='reset' value='reset' class='button2'>
      <input type='button' onclick='history.go(-1);' class='button2' value='back'>
      <input type='submit' value='send' name='send' class='button2'>
     </td>
    </tr>
</form>

Comment: Or to make it more simple.

If I have html code in a from, which I replace by using innerHTML.

is there a way the replaced html cannot be posted?